# How to set timeout to infinite to avoid MongoCursorTimeoutException in php

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am running the php script which fetch data from mongodb. I have a very huge database and I am getting this exception ..my mongodb version is 1.6.5

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' 
with message 'cursor timed out 
(timeout: 30000, time left: 0:0, status: 0)
```

My query is like this

```
private function executeRegex($start_date, $end_date, $source, $collection, $db)
  {
    $criteria = array(
        'date' => array(
          '$gte' => new MongoDate(strtotime($start_date)),
          '$lt' => new MongoDate(strtotime($end_date))
          ),  
        'uid'=> array(
          '$ne' => '-',
          ),  
        'source' => new MongoRegex($source)
        );  
    $value = $db->command(array('distinct' => $collection, 'key' => 'uid', 'query' => $criteria)); 
    return count($value['values']);
  }
```

how can I set timeout to infinite so that i do nt get this exception

Answer (score 21):

> **MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;**

type above line in your php code. this set timeout for all queries .
best regard,

Comment: Or you can do `MongoCursor::$timeout = $yourTimeInMS` to set any timeout you want before the query.

Comment: Note this is deprecated in >= 1.5

Comment: This was a good solution, unfortunately cannot be used with the latest php mongo driver, actually causing script to exit (depending on your error level setting)

Answer (score 12):

Here's documentation for setting the [timeout on a cursor](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php).

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->timeout(n);
```

The `command` method does not return a cursor it returns an array.

If you take a look at the documentation for the [command method](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php), you'll see that it's actually just a wrapper for the following:

```
public function command($data) {
    return $this->selectCollection('$cmd')->findOne($data);
}
```

That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Or just: MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;

Answer (score 5):

The PHP driver supports a second argument in the command method to set the timeout.

This means you should do the following:

```
$value = $db->command(
    array('distinct' => $collection, 'key' => 'uid', 'query' => $criteria),
    array('timeout' => 10000000000)
);
```

This should solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think, by the first step you should check how mongodb works with your query

```
db.collection.find(...).explain()
```

And, if needs add indexes to specified fields by

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(...)
```

And only than if your query is optimal, set timeout: -1